# WPform mailchimp API error while trying to add it

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3, wpforms

Hello I am new to mailchimp and to WP in general and I can not add the key to the WPform in order to link mailchimp to it.
I tried everything and nothing seems to work.
This is the error that I get.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either your API key is not correct or account nickname is not correct. Please make sure you're using the **Mailchimp API Key** and the **Account Nickname** is accurate.

I hope the two articles will help you to done the job:

https://mailchimp.com/help/about-api-keys/

https://wpforms.com/docs/install-use-mailchimp-addon-wpforms/

Regards

Sharif

Comment: Hello, already tried that and it is not working.